# How to create common footer in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

all

I can make the footer in a single page.

I know way that making footer in a single page.

Look like,

```
<ion-toolbar position="bottom">
```

but, I don't know how to attach single footer to all of my pages.

It can be my misunderstanding of Ionic2.

Thank you for reading my problem.

P.S I'm using tabs. maybe it causes some error for "ion-toolbar"

.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding my own footer components.

Thank you for reading.